# show filenames of file upload with console.log(req.files)

Tags: node.js, file-upload, filenames

I have a file upload with node js and multer and want to show the names of the uploaded files in the terminal. But I only get `Selected Files: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

```
router.post('/upload', function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        console.log('Selected Files: ' + req.files);
        if(err){
            res.end("Error: '" + err + "'");
        }else{
        console.log('Files uploaded!');
        res.sendStatus(204);
        }
    });
});
```

I also tried req.files.filename but it gave me the output: `Selected Files: undefined`

How can I show the names of the uploaded files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change

```
console.log('Selected Files: ' + req.files);
```

to

```
console.log('Selected Files: ', req.files);
```

Modern Browsers are able to display the data right.

**EDIT:**

If you only want the file names it´s not possible without collecting all the file names with one function and then print that out for example:

```
var fileNames = [];
req.files.forEach(function(element){
   fileNames.push(element.filename);
})

console.log('Selected Files: ', fileNames);
```

Comment: with fileNames.push(element.name) he throws: "Selected Files:  [ undefined, undefined ] " but with (element.filename) he gives the right output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get complete detail about the file use

```
console.log(req.file);
```